# shell script to append text in csv files based on constraints

Tags: command-line, shell-script

In my project, I have so many files named “config.csv”. My requirement is to add a Configuration at the end of the file based on certain constraints.

```
- Get All config.csv files across the project.
- The config.csv should have 7 columns.
- Add if the property does not exist then add one at the end of the file.
- Sometimes there might be a new line character at the end. sometimes there might not be.
```

The property looks like this.

```
1/1/1970,,propertyName,"Description of the Config","false",,1
```

How can I write a script to get this task done.

Disclaimer : I am new to scripting and want to automate the process of such task as much as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Create the following files:

`add_conf.awk`:

```
BEGIN {FS=","}
NF!=7 {bad=1; exit 1}
      {print}
END   {if (!bad) print "1/1/1970,,propertyName,\"Description of the Config\",\"false\",,1"}
```

`add_conf.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
tempfile=$(mktemp)

for f
do
        if awk -f add_conf.awk "$f" > "$tempfile"
        then
                cp "$tempfile" "$f"
        fi
done

rm "$tempfile"
```

and do `chmod +x add_conf.sh`.  (Of course you can put these files
somewhere other than the current directory;
just adjust the filename references accordingly.)  Then do

```
find . -name config.csv -type f -exec ./add_conf.sh {} +
```

The `find` command will find all plain files named `config.csv`
and pass their (path)names to `add_conf.sh`. 
That script invokes `awk` on each of the files,
writing the output to a temporary file. 
If the `awk` process reports success,
the script then copies the output back over the input file.

The `awk` script, `add_conf.awk`, sets the field separator (FS) to comma
(which is the obvious thing to do when dealing with a comma-separated file). 
If it encounters any line that has other than seven (comma-separated) fields,
it sets the `bad` flag and exits with a status of 1,
so the shell script will see that this file as non-qualifying
and will leave it alone. 
Otherwise, it prints each input line to the (temporary) output file. 
It will add a newline to the last line, if necessary. 
Then, if the file was OK up to the end, add the new data line.

Notes:

- The above is written for GNU `awk`. 
  POSIX `awk` does not specify behavior for input data not ending with newline,
  and it doesn’t support the `exit` command.
- I ignored your third bullet,
  “***if the property does not exist*** then add one at the end of the file.” 
  It can probably be added easily if you clarify what you mean.

Comment: what happens when "Description of the Config" has commas?

Comment: @codefreak: Strictly speaking, I'm not sure how *that* would matter, but I believe that you're really asking, "What if any of the pre-existing data in the file has a quoted comma within a value?"  And that's a valid point — awk's field splitting engine isn't smart enough to handle that correctly, so `NF` will not have the "right" value, and so tests based on `NF` may yield incorrect results.  `awk` is not a perfect tool for dealing with CSV data.

Comment: "What if any of the pre-existing data in the file has a quoted comma within a value?" that is exactly what I meant. @FurqanShaikh's best course may be to use some csv parsing tool or scripting language like python/ruby